# Angular 6 http put method not updating the data

Tags: angular

I have recently started working on Angular and have been using angular 6 and trying to call http.put method of my service into one of my component. There are no errors but the update is not happening.

- CORS is enabled.
- Tested successfully on Postman.
- As few online tutorials mentioned, I am subscribing to an Observable.

shared.service.ts:

```
`putTaskDetail(task: Task): Observable<Task> {    
const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content- 
Type':'application/json'}) };     
let constUrl = `${this.rootURL}`+'/UpdateTask';
return this.http.put<Task>(constUrl, task, httpOptions);    
}`
```

edit.component.ts:

```
`this.service.putTaskDetail(form.value).subscribe(
() => {          
this.toastr.success('Updated successfully.','Task Manager');
this.resetForm();
},
(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
console.log(err.message + " " + err.name);
}
)`
```

Kindly suggest, what could possibly be wrong here in the code.

Comment: gotta be an error somewhere

Comment: What does `form.value` contain?

Comment: Checked the network tab to see if the calls are successful?

Comment: I missed checking network tab, it does say this - [HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.]

Comment: @EdgarQuintero : form.value has my 'TaskDetail' object.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your `form.value` so people can help you debug. You could also try to change how you are creating your `http` options object like so:

```
private createHttpOptions() {
        const headersMap = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }   

        return {
            headers: new HttpHeaders(headersMap)
        };
    }
```

Then in your `put` just pass in `createHttpOptions`:

```
return this.http.put<T>(url, data, this.createHttpOptions());
```

NOTE: If you are sending a file, you don't need to send `headersMap`.